# nfs server on linux with windows 10 client

Tags: windows, nfs

I have a nfs server on a raspberry pi 3 b+, that share an ext4 directory. The nfs client is a windows 10 computer.

I have a problem with character encoding on client side. All accent characters are displayed badly (I am a french speaker, so some words have character like 'é' or 'è' for example).

My local setting on server side was en_US.UTF-8. I have changed it to fr_FR.UTF-8 but it change nothing. It seems that nfs version used is nfs v3. But I didn't manage to force it to v4. I have tried with a share directory on a ntfs partition, it's work fine and all wharacter well displayed.

Do you know what is the root cause of this type of problem ?

Comment: If my memory serve me right, NFS v2/v3 are all ASCII only. In NFS v4.1 is UTF-8 mandatory.

Comment: And please describe the changes you did to force NFS to v4 and log output related to nfs.